# save data in for loop but not save in loop

Tags: python, numpy

I extract the image to NumPy array and I select the first column from all images after that I append all first column from all images to save the first CSV file by for loop. For the second column, the third column, ... is the same method but it saves in finally not save in loop. This is my code, please tell and teach me.

```py
def image_2_data_2_GLCM305():
    images = glob.glob("*.jpg")
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(i)
        data = []
        for image in images:
            img = cv2.imread(image,0)
            img = img[i:i+1]    # 640*480==> (width * high)
            data.append(img)

        data1 = np.array(data)
        new_array = data1.reshape(numpic,-1) # number of image(จำนวนรูป)
        new_array = np.array(new_array)
        np.savetxt("Array.csv", new_array, delimiter=",", fmt='%.0f')
        np.save('outfile', new_array)
        print('*******************************')
        print(new_array.shape)
        print(new_array)
        np.savetxt('Array.csv', new_array, delimiter=",", fmt='%.0f')

print(image_2_data_2_GLCM305())
```

Comment: def image_2_data_2_GLCM305():
    images = glob.glob("*.jpg")
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(i)
        data = []
        for image in images:
            img = cv2.imread(image,0)
            img = img[i:i+1]    # 640*480==> (width * high)
            data.append(img)

        data1 = np.array(data)
        new_array = data1.reshape(numpic,-1) # number of image(จำนวนรูป)
        new_array = np.array(new_array)
        np.savetxt("Array.csv", new_array, delimiter=",", fmt='%.0f')
        np.save('outfile', new_array)

Answer (score 0):

Just save outside the loop. But your code has many inconsistency.

```
def image_2_data_2_GLCM305():
    images = glob.glob("*.jpg")
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(i)
        data = []
        for image in images:
            img = cv2.imread(image,0)
            img = img[i:i+1]    # 640*480==> (width * high) # why are you doing this? Do you just need a single pixel from the sequence of images?
            data.append(img)

    data1 = np.array(data)
    new_array = data1.reshape(numpic,-1) # number of image(จำนวนรูป)
    new_array = np.array(new_array)
    np.savetxt("Array.csv", new_array, delimiter=",", fmt='%.0f')
    np.save('outfile', new_array)
    print('*******************************')
    print(new_array.shape)
    print(new_array)
    np.savetxt('Array.csv', new_array, delimiter=",", fmt='%.0f')
```

Comment: thank you, I try before but not work, it save  first file only, next file no save